# Comparing pairs of objects

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This is a fairly simple question but I can't remember all my coding and data structures and feel a little blank.

Lets say I have a list/array of things (e.g. structures or objects). There is a certain property (true or false) that needs to hold between all pairs of these objects. What would be the fastest method to check if the property is violated between any pair of objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you have additional information about the property (for example, that it is transitive) your only solution is to check that property for every pair from the list, with two nested loops:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != N ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j != N ; j++)
        if (i != j) // This assumes that the property might not be reflexive
            // This will check the property both ways, i.e.
            // there is no implication that the property is commutative.
            checkProperty(list[i], list[j]);
```

For commutative properties (i.e. when `A ? B` implies `B ? A`) you can do it in half the comparisons by starting the second loop at `j = i+1`

If property is transitive (i.e. when `A ? B` and `B ? C` imply that `A ? C`, where `?` denotes the property check) you can build a faster check.

Comment: Thanks!. I was trying to avoid this but you are right. This property doesn't seem to be transitive so there is possibly no other way.

Comment: The statement about transitivity is correct in spirit, but lest other readers be confused, applying it is not as simple as doing a linear loop through pairs. You can do it in linear time with search, just not in linear order. If A?B is true and A?C is false, we can't conclude anything about A?C with just transitivity. Consider the transitive relation ⊂ = "is a subset of". Then with A = {a}, B = {a,b,c}, C = {a,b} we have A ⊂ B true, B ⊂ C false, and A ⊂ C true. But with C = {x}, A ⊂ B remains true, B ⊂ C is again false, but now A ⊂ C is false.

Comment: @A.Webb Thanks for a very thoughtful comment! I edited the answer to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a double loop to compare every item. Assuming you just need to check every 2-item combination (i.e. order doesn't matter), you can just loop through the remaining items in the inner loop.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < N ; i++)
    for (int j = i+1 ; j < N ; j++)
            checkProperty(list[i], list[j]);
```